# Recursion! I'm creating a method that counts back up and then down to a certain number, but I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop

Tags: java, recursion

So, I am currently creating a method for an assignment using recursion. I need to take an int, then print going down until it hits 0. After that, I need to print going up until it hits the original number, then stopping. Here's my code so far.

```
 public static void recursivePrinter(int levels)
{
   final int start = levels;

    if (levels < start ) {
        System.out.println("Going up! " + levels);
        recursivePrinter(levels + 1);
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Going down! " + levels);
        recursivePrinter(levels - 1);
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Your code doesn't reference `0` at any point, that should be a clue. Also, if you assign levels to start and then check if `levels < start`, it will naturally never be true.

Comment: You're never ending the recursion.  There's no condition here which *doesn't* call the recursive method again.  There has to be some logic in your method which examines the current state and decides *not* to call itself again.  Also, does this code *always* execute the `else` block?

Comment: At no point in your code do you check if you're at 0. You just go down one, reset your current level, and repeat. You could have a method with 2 variables as parametres, `start_level` and `current_level`, and at some point have a condition (e.g., `current_level == 0`) where you don't continue the recursion.

Comment: Well first of all you're going to need the original value. You could pass that as a parameter, so change your method signature to `public static void recursivePrinter(int currentLevel, int maxLevel)`

Comment: @David As of right now, I don't think so, but it's supposed to.

Comment: @AnnaBelle: It's "supposed to" do what, exactly?  Under what condition should this function *not* recursively call itself?

Comment: @David Say levels = 3. It's supposed to count down from 3 (3, 2, 1) and then back up to 3 (1, 2, 3).

Comment: @David I added a base case and used recursion to just count down from the original number, but now I'm not sure how to count back up to it.

Comment: @AnnaBelle: So it sounds like your method should do these operations: (1) If the argument is 0, return.  (2) Print the argument.  (3) Recursively call with "argument - 1".  (4) Print the argument again.  The "counting back up" will happen naturally as the recursive calls return to each other and control moves back up the stack.  You don't even need to store a copy of the argument in a variable anywhere.

Comment: @David Thank you. I was just overthinking this entire thing. I didn't think it would be as simple as just printing the argument.

Answer (score 1):

You don't reach the return; statement. the code always go in the else statement. to keep track of the starting number you could use a global variable . also you need to add a condition where the recursion should finish. so you can try some thing like this :

```
static int start = 10;


     public static void recursivePrinter(int levels)
         {


             if (levels < start ) {
                 System.out.println("Going up! " + levels);
                 recursivePrinter(levels + 1);
             }
             else {
                 System.out.println("Going down! " + levels);
                // recursivePrinter(levels - 1);
                 start-- ;
             }
             return;
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

In an attempt to provide a meaningful answer to help future visitors (as opposed to the comment thread on the question above)...

The initial problem was two-fold:

1. The method had no condition in which it *doesn't* recursively call itself.  Which results in an infinite recursion.  There must *always* be some condition by which the method *stops* recursion.
2. The method was locally storing a value that it doesn't need, and the logic was incorrectly assuming that value won't be different for each call to the method.

Essentially, a recursive method almost always follows a basic structure:

```
method(argument) {
    terminating condition;
    state change or method action;
    recursive call;
}
```

Depending on the state change or the method action, this can be a bit more complex.  But the basic components are generally always there in one form or another.

In your case, the `argument` is an integer, the `terminating condition` is testing whether that integer is a known value, the `state change` is changing the integer, the `method action` is printing the integer, and the `recursive call` is invoking the method with the new integer.

Based on your comment above:

> It's supposed to count down from 3 (3, 2, 1) and then back up to 3 (1, 2, 3).

Consider the following pseudo-code (so as to not do your homework for you) structure:

```
myMethod(level) {
    // terminating condition
    if level is 0
      return

    // method action
    print level

    // recurse
    myMethod(level - 1)
}
```

This would be a great time to step through the code in your debugger and see what a recursive method call actually does.  Each time the method is invoked, it's an isolated action unaware of any other invocations of the method.  It's "building a stack" of calls to itself.  When the terminating condition is reached, that stack will "unwind" and those calls will all return to each other in reverse order.

Given this, printing the numbers "counting back up" is a natural result of just printing it again in the method:

```
myMethod(level) {
    // terminating condition
    if level is 0
      return

    // method action
    print level

    // recurse
    myMethod(level - 1)

    // more method action
    print level
}
```

That last operation simply prints the value a second time.  But it does so *after* the recursive call, therefore after *all* printing of lower numbers done within that recursive call, regardless of how many there are.